# Session is expiring after returning from the other website(payment)

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

I am using session mode as sqlserver am facing the problem of session expiry after returning from the payment page am developing an e commerce website when the payment result gets completed 
 the session is expiring am unable to handle the things like storing the results in the db and sending emails as the session expires. Is there any way to handle the things after payment other than sessions.please help me Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method previously in the sequential order as below;

1. Browse the website
2. Fill the shopping cart with items
3. On Checkout,  allow to login
4. After successful login, establish a session variable for the user (e.g. user name)
5. verify the shopping cart
6. On payment, post required values to payment site and set the return TO parameter
   as your site
7. on successful payment, return to your site and access
   the session variable (user name)

There are couple of things you can check;

See that you are setting the correct session variable
and also you are returning to the correct site address (note that server maintains sessions based on the site name and in some cases IP address reference)

Happy coding..!!